# How to control NumberInput using any buttons in ChakraUI?

Tags: chakra-ui

I am using `NumberInput` in ChakraUI as follows:

```
<NumberInput
    defaultValue={value}
    min={0.00001}
    type="type"
    size="md"
    onChange={setValue}
>
    <NumberInputField />
    <NumberInputStepper>
        <NumberIncrementStepper />
        <NumberDecrementStepper />
    </NumberInputStepper>
</NumberInput>
```

For now, as you can see, I only have increment and decrement steppers.
But I also want to add buttons such as `Clear`, `+10`, `+100`, `+1000`, etc.

Apparently, I can easily handle the value change by calling `setValue`, when the button is pressed. However, how to make the change displayed in the `NumberInputField`?

I only found `useNumberInput` hook provided bu ChakraUI. However, it is pretty limited and works only for increment/decrement cases with some fixed step.
I also found that I could put values to the `Box` and make it like `<Box>{value}</Box>`, but then it won't be possible to type anything inside the box.
So I'm pretty confused about how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is pass in your stateful `value` as the `value` prop for the NumberInput, like so:

```
<NumberInput
    defaultValue={value}
    min={0.00001}
    type="type"
    size="md"
    onChange={setValue}
    value={value}
>
    <NumberInputField />
    <NumberInputStepper>
        <NumberIncrementStepper />
        <NumberDecrementStepper />
    </NumberInputStepper>
</NumberInput>
```